# Vba use cell value as name

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to use the value of a cell as a name for this cell (in a range of cells).
Basically, I try to do something like :

```
For Each Cell In MyIDRange
    Cell.Name = Cell.Value2   
Next Cell
```

The problem is "that name is not valid". I tried to use CStr(Cell.Value2), but I always get the error.

Comment: Are we talking about named ranges?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add names (as i mentioned in comment), please see this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835300%28v=office.15%29.aspx

```
For Each c In MyIDRange
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add _ 
        Name := c.Value, _ 
        RefersTo := c.Address 
Next c
```

Do not use built-in object names as name of variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will change my variable names. Otherwise, I still get the same error by replacing my code with yours.

Comment: Does the names contain spaces? Please, show my your data.

Comment: The concerned data looks like this : ID
1.1   
1.1.1   
1.1.2   
1.1.3   
1.2   
1.2.1   
1.2.2   
1.2.3   
1.3 Where ID is the name of the column

Comment: Replace dots with underscores and try again.

Comment: I tried with the underscores, I still have the error.

Comment: Even if I replace that line with    For Each c In MyIDRange
    c.Name = CStr(i)
    i = i + 1
Next c      I still have the same error. I don't understand why it doesn't work, I have used that piece of code before.

Comment: I debugged the code and the error appears at the 2nd loop.